# How is it Possible that React Sites are Static?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been working on a personal React project with a NodeJS/Express backend (I'm fairly new at this still). Being a good way through the project, I wanted to figure out the best way (in terms of the [5 Pillars of the AWS Well Architectured Principles](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/the-5-pillars-of-the-aws-well-architected-framework/)) to finally deploy my react app.

Although I had some of my own ideas, I pulled out google and searched for it ("best way to deploy react app") to see if others have already been through this with best practices. The first things that popped up are sites like [this](https://blog.bitsrc.io/8-react-application-deployment-and-hosting-options-for-2019-ab4d668309fd) and [this](https://codebrahma.com/deploy-react-application-depth-overview-various-options-deploy/). The suggestions were "use an S3 bucket" or "put it on Github pages."

I feel like I'm missing something:

1. How is it possible that React apps are static when the content on the pages seem to change based on certain requests and responses?
2. How can I tell whether it's possible to deploy my React app statically (and deploy my backend separately) and just throw it in an S3 bucket or whether I need to run my React app in a server?

I've always been under the impression that my application is dynamic as I allow users to do actions such as signup and login...

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the "React" part is throwing you off.  Your question is exactly the same whether it's React, Angular, jQuery or "Vanilla" JavaScript. The important question is: how do you leverage as much static rendering as possible even though your application is "dynamic" (aka changes content based on user events).

The first thing to remember is that when you build a React application, it spits out static assets.. an index.html file that references a JavaScript file, css file, etc. You can chuck the folder with those files into an S3 bucket and bam, static website. The fact that the DOM elements are created at runtime and users interact with an api that loads content dynamically doesn't change the fact that your initial payload is static, just like every html page you load in your browser.

**note:** You don't *have* to build React applications, but typically you do in order to transform JSX -> JavaScript, that is to say, you don't need JSX to write a React application.

The next thing to remember is that React can be used server side to render templates, just like old school php + html (or whatever): https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html . This has been part of the React API for a very long time. This means that your initial payload can contain the DOM elements without needing to load any JavaScript in your browser at all. Then when users interact with your api you can load more stuff dynamically, or you can send the user another html payload that was rendered server side. Obviously nowadays that's not very typical, instead the former approach is used where just the initial DOM is rendered serverside, and more content is loaded in real time.

There are a number of libraries that help with static rendering, https://github.com/react-static/react-static for instance.

You can use tools like this to spit out many html pages. This is helpful when you know what the content is going to be ahead of time. Obviously if something is truly dynamic like filtering a table of data that's the result of an api call, you're not going to have html pages with every possible prerendered DOM. Some stuff is just dynamic, but that's the same no matter what JavaScript library you're using.

Answer (score 7):

The 'static-ness' of an HTML page that has no dynamic JS-powered functionality is not the same thing as a static site. 'Static' refers to the assets that are loaded by the page, which can include JS script assets. When you configure a server to serve a directory of files as if it's a website, that's a static site.

React applications (and any JS framework apps) don't need to make requests to a server, though they can. Whether you can build a static site without writing server code depends on your application's use case. If you need to store user data, a static site alone won't cut it.

To address your first question: the server that serves your static assets doesn't have to be the same server that handles responding to your application's requests. I can serve my static assets from a fast, nginx-based server behind `mysite.com`, and handle app traffic at `api.mysite.com`, which routes to my express server.

In this way, the page the browser loads is 'static', e.g. it always receives the same files. But those files include scripts that know how to talk to my app server.